# How to deploy contract to the Ropsten test-net using web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, testnets, ropsten

I am newbie in solidity.
I don't understand what steps I must do for deploy contract in the **Ropsten** test-net.

This is my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import './ERC20.sol';
import './SafeMath.sol';

contract StepanToken2 is ERC20{
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address public ownerFirst;
    address public ownerSecond;

    string public constant name = "Stepan Token";
    string public constant symbol = "SPT";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 8; 
    uint totalTokens = 100000000000000;


    //balances for accaunts
    mapping(address => uint) balances;

    //Owner of account approves the transfer of an amount to another account
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


    function StepanToken2 (address _ownerFirst, address _ownerSecond){
       ownerFirst = _ownerFirst;
       ownerSecond = _ownerSecond;

       balances[ownerFirst] = SafeMath.div(totalTokens, 3);
       balances[ownerSecond] = SafeMath.sub(totalTokens, balances[ownerFirst]);
    }

    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 totalSupply){
         return totalTokens;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance){
         return balances[_owner];
    }


    function transfer(address _to, uint _value)  returns (bool success){
            require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0 && SafeMath.add(balances[_to], _value) > balances[_to]);
                balances[msg.sender] = SafeMath.sub(balances[msg.sender],_value);
                balances[_to] = SafeMath.add(balances[_to], _value);
                Transfer(msg.sender,  _to, _value);
                return true;     
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success){
        require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0 && SafeMath.add(balances[_to], _value) > 0);
            balances[_from] = SafeMath.sub(balances[_from], _value);
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] = SafeMath.sub(allowed[_from][msg.sender], _value);
            balances[_to] = SafeMath.add(balances[_to], _value);
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
    }


    function approve(address _spender, uint _value)  returns (bool success){
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender,  _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining){
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

}
```

And it compiles and migrates normal.
When contract will compiling in ropsten I should set parameters in constructor contract. 
I have created an HTML file with JS for this contract:

var Web3 = require('web3');
        var web3 = new Web3();

```
    function initConnectWeb3() {

            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/[infura_api_key]"));


        console.log(web3);
    }

    initConnectWeb3();

    primaryAddress = web3.eth.accounts[0];
    var MyContract = web3.eth.contract([{
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "name",
            "outputs": [{
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [{
                    "name": "_spender",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_value",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "approve",
            "outputs": [{
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "totalSupply",
            "outputs": [{
                "name": "totalSupply",
                "type": "uint256"
            }],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [{
                    "name": "_from",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_to",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_value",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "transferFrom",
            "outputs": [{
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "decimals",
            "outputs": [{
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint8"
            }],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "ownerFirst",
            "outputs": [{
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [{
                "name": "_owner",
                "type": "address"
            }],
            "name": "balanceOf",
            "outputs": [{
                "name": "balance",
                "type": "uint256"
            }],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "symbol",
            "outputs": [{
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [{
                    "name": "_to",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_value",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "transfer",
            "outputs": [{
                "name": "success",
                "type": "bool"
            }],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [{
                    "name": "_owner",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_spender",
                    "type": "address"
                }
            ],
            "name": "allowance",
            "outputs": [{
                "name": "remaining",
                "type": "uint256"
            }],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "ownerSecond",
            "outputs": [{
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [{
                    "name": "_ownerFirst",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_ownerSecond",
                    "type": "address"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "type": "constructor"
        },
        {
            "anonymous": false,
            "inputs": [{
                    "indexed": true,
                    "name": "_from",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "name": "_to",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "name": "_value",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Transfer",
            "type": "event"
        },
        {
            "anonymous": false,
            "inputs": [{
                    "indexed": true,
                    "name": "_owner",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "name": "_spender",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": false,
                    "name": "_value",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Approval",
            "type": "event"
        }
    ]);

    // contact = MyContract.new(0xC0b4ec83028307053Fbe8d00ba4372384fe4b52B, 0x4E90a36B45879F5baE71B57Ad525e817aFA54890, {from: primaryAddress,  gas: 50000});
    contract = MyContract.new("0xC0b4ec83028307053Fbe8d00ba4372384fe4b52B", "0x4E90a36B45879F5baE71B57Ad525e817aFA54890", {
        from: primaryAddress,
        gas: 50000
        // data: evmCode
    }, function (err, contract) {
        if (!err && contract.address)
            console.log(contract.address);
    });
```

I have added changes to my [script](https://github.com/poperechnyi1/SPT--SecondTry)

And now I have problem with:
[image]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Try my tutorial https://erc20token.sonnguyen.ws/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this NodeJS solution:

```
module.paths.push('/usr/lib/node_modules');

var fs = require('fs');
const contract_data = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync('path to your JSON file')
);


var openKey = "open Key (address)";
var privateKey = "privateKey";


var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/ "));

web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add("0x" + privateKey);

var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract_data.abi);

contract.deploy({
    data: contract_data.unlinked_binary,
    arguments: []
}).send({
    from: openKey,
    gas: 1500000,
    gasPrice: '80000000'
}, function (error, transactionHash) {

}).on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
}).on('transactionHash', function (transactionHash) {
    console.log('transactionHash', transactionHash);
}).on('receipt', function (receipt) {
    console.log('receipt', receipt.contractAddress);
}).on('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {
    console.log('confirmation', confirmationNumber);
});
```

Comment: On web3 `0.20.1`, I am getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` on the line `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(...)`... Is it different for `0.20.1`?

Answer (score 5):

You can deploy this contract in another way:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var util = require('ethereumjs-util');
var tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/...'));
var address = '...';
var key ='...';
var bytecode = '...';
var interface = [...];

function sendRaw(rawTx) {
    var privateKey = new Buffer(key, 'hex');
    var transaction = new tx(rawTx);
    transaction.sign(privateKey);
    var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(
    '0x' + serializedTx, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}

var rawTx = {
    nonce: web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)),
    gasLimit: web3.toHex(1500000),
    gasPrice: web3.toHex(80000000),
    data: bytecode 
};
sendRaw(rawTx);
```

Answer (score 3):

at first glance, i think your mistake is using addresses without quotes "" or ' in this line :

```
MyContract.new([0xC0b4ec83028307053Fbe8d00ba4372384fe4b52B, 0x4E90a36B45879F5baE71B57Ad525e817aFA54890], {}...
```

besides you have to provide two addresses not an array of addresses

```
MyContract.new('0xC0b4ec83028307053Fbe8d00ba4372384fe4b52B', '0x4E90a36B45879F5baE71B57Ad525e817aFA54890', {}...
```

as the constructor :

```
 function StepanToken2 (address _ownerFirst, address _ownerSecond)
```

accepts 2 arguments not an array.

Comment: I changed my code and I have same problem which I had on picture.

Comment: try MyContract.new('0xC0b4ec83028307053Fbe8d00ba4372384fe4b52B', '0x4E90a36B45879F5baE71B57Ad525e817aFA54890', {}... without array brackets

Comment: THanks I do it the same as you. But in result I have error "Invalid address" My code contract = MyContract.new('0xC0b4ec83028307053Fbe8d00ba4372384fe4b52B', '0x4E90a36B45879F5baE71B57Ad525e817aFA54890', {
            from: primaryAddress,
            gas: 50000
            // data: evmCode
        }, function (err, contract) {
            if (!err && contract.address)
                console.log(contract.address);
        });

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your default address. Use the following command to set that **web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];**. And also make sure your account is unlocked using web3.personal.unlockAccount().

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a suite of scripts for interacting with smart contracts (the Solidity variant) at https://github.com/fixone/ethdemo. You can check the steps in https://github.com/fixone/ethdemo/blob/master/compile-sign-deploy.js and please note that it assumes that the solc binary is invoked (in the 'exec' function to compile the contract)

Comment: Thanks for adding the scripts, but also consider answering the question by pointing what should be modified in order for the question to be answered. (I am aware that the question is also lacking vital information)